# What does this error mean: Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. (full error in the question)

Tags: java, minecraft

I have been making a few mods for Minecraft. I made around 5 with no errors. Then this one came up.

```
[Netty Server IO #1/FATAL]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.minecraft.network.EnumConnectionState
```

It crashed the game and it came up when I opened a world in my mod. I tried deleting and reinstalling that class & googling the general error, but wasn't successful. I asked the Hypixel forums before I came here but no one replied. Any help would be nice, if you need the actual class here it is, it may be too much though:

```
package net.minecraft.network;

import com.google.common.collect.BiMap;
import com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import net.minecraft.network.handshake.client.C00Handshake;
import net.minecraft.network.login.client.CPacketEncryptionResponse;
import net.minecraft.network.login.client.CPacketLoginStart;
import net.minecraft.network.login.server.SPacketEnableCompression;
import net.minecraft.network.login.server.SPacketEncryptionRequest;
import net.minecraft.network.login.server.SPacketLoginSuccess;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketAnimation;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketChatMessage;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketClickWindow;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketClientSettings;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketClientStatus;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketCloseWindow;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketConfirmTeleport;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketConfirmTransaction;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketCreativeInventoryAction;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketCustomPayload;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketEnchantItem;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketEntityAction;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketHeldItemChange;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketInput;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketKeepAlive;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketPlayer;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketPlayerAbilities;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketPlayerDigging;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketPlayerTryUseItem;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketPlayerTryUseItemOnBlock;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketResourcePackStatus;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketSpectate;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketSteerBoat;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketTabComplete;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketUpdateSign;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketUseEntity;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketVehicleMove;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketAnimation;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketBlockAction;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketBlockBreakAnim;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketBlockChange;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketCamera;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketChangeGameState;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketChat;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketChunkData;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketCloseWindow;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketCollectItem;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketCombatEvent;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketConfirmTransaction;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketCooldown;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketCustomPayload;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketCustomSound;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketDestroyEntities;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketDisconnect;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketDisplayObjective;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketEffect;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketEntity;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketEntityAttach;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketEntityEffect;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketEntityEquipment;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketEntityHeadLook;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketEntityMetadata;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketEntityProperties;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketEntityStatus;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketEntityTeleport;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketEntityVelocity;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketExplosion;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketHeldItemChange;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketJoinGame;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketKeepAlive;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketMaps;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketMoveVehicle;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketMultiBlockChange;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketOpenWindow;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketParticles;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketPlayerAbilities;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketPlayerListHeaderFooter;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketPlayerListItem;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketPlayerPosLook;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketRemoveEntityEffect;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketResourcePackSend;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketRespawn;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketScoreboardObjective;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketServerDifficulty;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketSetExperience;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketSetPassengers;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketSetSlot;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketSignEditorOpen;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketSoundEffect;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketSpawnExperienceOrb;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketSpawnGlobalEntity;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketSpawnMob;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketSpawnObject;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketSpawnPainting;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketSpawnPlayer;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketSpawnPosition;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketStatistics;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketTabComplete;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketTeams;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketTimeUpdate;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketTitle;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketUnloadChunk;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketUpdateBossInfo;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketUpdateHealth;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketUpdateScore;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketUpdateTileEntity;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketUseBed;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketWindowItems;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketWindowProperty;
import net.minecraft.network.play.server.SPacketWorldBorder;
import net.minecraft.network.status.client.CPacketPing;
import net.minecraft.network.status.client.CPacketServerQuery;
import net.minecraft.network.status.server.SPacketPong;
import net.minecraft.network.status.server.SPacketServerInfo;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public enum EnumConnectionState
{
    HANDSHAKING(-1)
    {
        {
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, C00Handshake.class);
        }
    },
    PLAY(0)
    {
        {
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketSpawnObject.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketSpawnExperienceOrb.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketSpawnGlobalEntity.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketSpawnMob.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketSpawnPainting.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketSpawnPlayer.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketAnimation.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketStatistics.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketBlockBreakAnim.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketUpdateTileEntity.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketBlockAction.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketBlockChange.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketUpdateBossInfo.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketServerDifficulty.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketTabComplete.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketChat.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketMultiBlockChange.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketConfirmTransaction.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketCloseWindow.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketOpenWindow.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketWindowItems.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketWindowProperty.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketSetSlot.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketCooldown.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketCustomPayload.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketCustomSound.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketDisconnect.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketEntityStatus.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketExplosion.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketUnloadChunk.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketChangeGameState.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketKeepAlive.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketChunkData.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketEffect.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketParticles.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketJoinGame.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketMaps.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketEntity.S15PacketEntityRelMove.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketEntity.S17PacketEntityLookMove.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketEntity.S16PacketEntityLook.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketEntity.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketMoveVehicle.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketSignEditorOpen.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketPlayerAbilities.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketCombatEvent.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketPlayerListItem.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketPlayerPosLook.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketUseBed.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketDestroyEntities.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketRemoveEntityEffect.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketResourcePackSend.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketRespawn.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketEntityHeadLook.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketWorldBorder.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketCamera.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketHeldItemChange.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketDisplayObjective.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketEntityMetadata.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketEntityAttach.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketEntityVelocity.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketEntityEquipment.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketSetExperience.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketUpdateHealth.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketScoreboardObjective.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketSetPassengers.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketTeams.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketUpdateScore.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketSpawnPosition.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketTimeUpdate.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketTitle.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketSoundEffect.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketPlayerListHeaderFooter.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketCollectItem.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketEntityTeleport.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketEntityProperties.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketEntityEffect.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketConfirmTeleport.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketTabComplete.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketChatMessage.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketClientStatus.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketClientSettings.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketConfirmTransaction.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketEnchantItem.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketClickWindow.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketCloseWindow.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketCustomPayload.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketUseEntity.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketKeepAlive.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketPlayer.Position.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketPlayer.PositionRotation.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketPlayer.Rotation.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketPlayer.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketVehicleMove.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketSteerBoat.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketPlayerAbilities.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketPlayerDigging.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketEntityAction.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketInput.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketResourcePackStatus.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketHeldItemChange.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketCreativeInventoryAction.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketUpdateSign.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketAnimation.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketSpectate.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketPlayerTryUseItemOnBlock.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketPlayerTryUseItem.class);
        }
    },
    STATUS(1)
    {
        {
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketServerQuery.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketServerInfo.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketPing.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketPong.class);
        }
    },
    LOGIN(2)
    {
        {
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, net.minecraft.network.login.server.SPacketDisconnect.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketEncryptionRequest.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketLoginSuccess.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.CLIENTBOUND, SPacketEnableCompression.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketLoginStart.class);
            this.registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection.SERVERBOUND, CPacketEncryptionResponse.class);
        }
    };

    private static int MIN_PROTOCOL_ID = -1;
    private static int MAX_PROTOCOL_ID = 2;
    private static final EnumConnectionState[] STATES_BY_ID = new EnumConnectionState[MAX_PROTOCOL_ID - MIN_PROTOCOL_ID + 1];
    private static final Map < Class <? extends Packet<? >> , EnumConnectionState > STATES_BY_CLASS = Maps. < Class <? extends Packet<? >> , EnumConnectionState > newHashMap();
    private final int id;
    private final Map < EnumPacketDirection, BiMap < Integer, Class <? extends Packet<? >>> > directionMaps;

    private EnumConnectionState(int protocolId)
    {
        this.directionMaps = Maps.newEnumMap(EnumPacketDirection.class);
        this.id = protocolId;
    }

    protected EnumConnectionState registerPacket(EnumPacketDirection direction, Class <? extends Packet<? >> packetClass)
    {
        BiMap < Integer, Class <? extends Packet<? >>> bimap = (BiMap)this.directionMaps.get(direction);

        if (bimap == null)
        {
            bimap = HashBiMap. < Integer, Class <? extends Packet<? >>> create();
            this.directionMaps.put(direction, bimap);
        }

        if (bimap.containsValue(packetClass))
        {
            String s = direction + " packet " + packetClass + " is already known to ID " + bimap.inverse().get(packetClass);
            LogManager.getLogger().fatal(s);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(s);
        }
        else
        {
            bimap.put(Integer.valueOf(bimap.size()), packetClass);
            return this;
        }
    }

    public Integer getPacketId(EnumPacketDirection direction, Packet<?> packetIn)
    {
        return (Integer)((BiMap)this.directionMaps.get(direction)).inverse().get(packetIn.getClass());
    }

    @Nullable
    public Packet<?> getPacket(EnumPacketDirection direction, int packetId) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class <? extends Packet<? >> oclass = (Class)((BiMap)this.directionMaps.get(direction)).get(Integer.valueOf(packetId));
        return oclass == null ? null : (Packet)oclass.newInstance();
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }

    public static EnumConnectionState getById(int stateId)
    {
        return stateId >= MIN_PROTOCOL_ID && stateId <= MAX_PROTOCOL_ID ? STATES_BY_ID[stateId - MIN_PROTOCOL_ID] : null;
    }

    public static EnumConnectionState getFromPacket(Packet<?> packetIn)
    {
        return (EnumConnectionState)STATES_BY_CLASS.get(packetIn.getClass());
    }

    static {
        for (EnumConnectionState enumconnectionstate : values())
        {
            int i = enumconnectionstate.getId();

            if (i < MIN_PROTOCOL_ID || i > MAX_PROTOCOL_ID)
            {
                throw new Error("Invalid protocol ID " + Integer.toString(i));
            }

            STATES_BY_ID[i - MIN_PROTOCOL_ID] = enumconnectionstate;

            for (EnumPacketDirection enumpacketdirection : enumconnectionstate.directionMaps.keySet())
            {
                for (Class <? extends Packet<? >> oclass : (enumconnectionstate.directionMaps.get(enumpacketdirection)).values())
                {
                    if (STATES_BY_CLASS.containsKey(oclass) && STATES_BY_CLASS.get(oclass) != enumconnectionstate)
                    {
                        throw new Error("Packet " + oclass + " is already assigned to protocol " + STATES_BY_CLASS.get(oclass) + " - can\'t reassign to " + enumconnectionstate);
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        oclass.newInstance();
                    }
                    catch (Throwable var10)
                    {
                        throw new Error("Packet " + oclass + " fails instantiation checks! " + oclass);
                    }

                    STATES_BY_CLASS.put(oclass, enumconnectionstate);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also got a crash report here it is:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// I let you down. Sorry :(

Time: 7/6/20 4:43 PM
Description: Updating screen events

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.minecraft.network.EnumConnectionState
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.launchIntegratedServer(Minecraft.java:2452)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiListWorldSelectionEntry.loadWorld(GuiListWorldSelectionEntry.java:246)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiListWorldSelectionEntry.joinWorld(GuiListWorldSelectionEntry.java:200)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiListWorldSelectionEntry.mousePressed(GuiListWorldSelectionEntry.java:164)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiListExtended.mouseClicked(GuiListExtended.java:54)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiWorldSelection.mouseClicked(GuiWorldSelection.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen.handleMouseInput(GuiScreen.java:595)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiWorldSelection.handleMouseInput(GuiWorldSelection.java:50)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen.handleInput(GuiScreen.java:564)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.runTick(Minecraft.java:1821)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.runGameLoop(Minecraft.java:1147)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:454)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:115)
    at Start.main(Start.java:11)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.launchIntegratedServer(Minecraft.java:2452)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiListWorldSelectionEntry.loadWorld(GuiListWorldSelectionEntry.java:246)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiListWorldSelectionEntry.joinWorld(GuiListWorldSelectionEntry.java:200)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiListWorldSelectionEntry.mousePressed(GuiListWorldSelectionEntry.java:164)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiListExtended.mouseClicked(GuiListExtended.java:54)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiWorldSelection.mouseClicked(GuiWorldSelection.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen.handleMouseInput(GuiScreen.java:595)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiWorldSelection.handleMouseInput(GuiWorldSelection.java:50)
    at net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreen.handleInput(GuiScreen.java:564)

-- Affected screen --
Details:
    Screen name: net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiScreenWorking
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.runTick(Minecraft.java:1821)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.runGameLoop(Minecraft.java:1147)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:454)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:115)
    at Start.main(Start.java:11)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.9.4
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_251, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 715557096 bytes (682 MB) / 1037959168 bytes (989 MB) up to 1037959168 bytes (989 MB)
    JVM Flags: 3 total; -Xincgc -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 12, tallocated: 94
    Launched Version: mcp
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 GL version 4.6.0 - Build 26.20.100.7262, Intel
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using GL 1.3 texture combiners.
Using framebuffer objects because OpenGL 3.0 is supported and separate blending is supported.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.
VBOs are available because OpenGL 1.5 is supported.

    Using VBOs: No
    Is Modded: Very likely; Jar signature invalidated
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: net.minecraft.client.Minecraft$15@703947bd
```

***SIDE NOTE** I never actually interfered with that class, I did use packets in my mods though, so maybe that was it.

Comment: So if I delete the static initializers it will fix? When I try to change them it just results in more errors.

Comment: Have you tried to change all the `static` variables?